# mysql returning data when a where clause failes

Tags: c#, mysql

I've though a IFNUll would work in this case but it doesn't here's the query i'm using.

```
SELECT IFNULL(ColumnB,0)
      FROM points
     WHERE points.keyid = schedule.Week3)
      AS ColumnB
```

The problem is this returns 14 rows, and 2 of these rows do not match points.keyid = schedule.Week3 (which is expected).  So 2 rows return nothing, and if it's nothing I want to select the data as 0, because i need to average all 52 weeks.

Comment: That whole query seems to be invalid.

Comment: well thats because that query is repeated about 52 times for seperate weeks

Comment: I don't see how that makes it valid. It's an incomplete query, adding a column alias that doesn't make sense, and referring to a table that is not actually used. How are we expected to help you to a solution with this (lack of) information? Post the whole query, you don't have to pay per char on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines a bit, since the query you posted seems to be missing a few things, I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ColumnB, 0)
    FROM points p
        LEFT JOIN schedule s
            ON p.keyid = s.Week3
```